# How to call any function in Microsoft Access?

Tags: ms-access

I've what seems a trivial thing to do in MS Access 2016, but can't get it right.

I have a table named "Values", and I want to get the Length of a column named Value_Name which is of data type "short text"

So I click Create > Query Design. I show table "Values". I double click column "Value_Name" so it's the first field. I click in the second column, and for a Field value I enter:

```
Length of value: Len(Value_Name)
```

If I click anywhere else, I get a pop-up error saying "There was an error compiling this function. The Visual Basic module contains a syntax error." When I close the error it highlights "Len" in my Field.

I've tried with several functions (replace, left, etc) and can't get any to not give the above error, even when adding the column with the "Build..." right click menu.

So I edit the SQL directly, and enter:

```
SELECT Len("Test") AS TestLength;
```

And this gets "Compile error. in query expression 'Len("Test"'.

... and yes, the error message has a period after the word "error" for some reason.

Comment: The "Test" SQL works for me. Do any other intrinsic functions like Date() work? Does function work in a textbox?

Comment: I tried a few other functions like replace and left, with the same error. I can reproduce the error on two separate installs of access 2016, under separate domains which were installed from different installation media.

Comment: This type of error can occur when a library has been selected in the VBA references list but the library is not actually available for the installed Access. This has happened to me when I open a file created with later version of Access.

Comment: Does that happen with built-in functions like Len? It's happening both on my company's installation of access, and on one of our customer's installation.

Comment: It can but no assurance that is your issue. Did you look for missing library in VBA selected references list? If no missing library then I have to say it is the Access install itself that is issue.

Comment: VBA selected references? Where do I see this? I'm not writing a program or VBA script, I'm just using the Access UI to make a query. I'm not explicitly using any VBA.

Comment: Did you build this db or was it given to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In queries specifically, this issue occurs when VBA has a problem compiling some code.

As June7 hinted, it may be caused by a missing reference, but only if there's some VBA code failing to compile. It can be code with plain syntax errors too.

To track down this code, enter the VBA editor (Alt + F11) and hit Debug -> Compile Database. The editor should point you close to the code that's failing to compile, which you'll have to fix.

Comment: There's no user-written VBA though, I'm just using the Access UI to list records in a table and show the length of one of the columns. I mean perhaps Access is internally using VBA, is this what you mean?

Comment: Are you _100%_ sure there's no user written VBA? I've encountered others experiencing the same issue, in my experience there's always some "VBA" that somehow accidentally got added on a form and is not valid at all (because it wasn't added on purpose). If I were you, I'd check.

Comment: If seems to complain about WNetGetUser in mpr.dll. from the lengthy error it seems it needs updating for the 64-bit system. Seeing this was installed with a 64-bit installer on this 64-bit machine, I would assume the installer did the wrong thing.

Comment: Erik: the copy on my machine is a fresh install of Access, which I installed myself from a Microsoft provided installer. So I'm fairly certain :⁠-⁠) though the database on the customer's has a WNGetUser call which might be custom (I couldn't know)

Comment: That sounds like an external function declaration in VBA that you will have to adjust for 64-bits pointer support yourself, not an issue with the installation.